# Boostrap Button Hover Inherit Class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, class, inheritance

In short, I have a `.btn-info` button, and when I hover my mouse over it, I want to change the class to `.btn-danger`. And obviously when I am no longer hovering I want the default class to be `.btn-info`. How can I accomplish this with CSS?

Comment: CSS alone cannot change the class. You either need Javascript to do that, or have a special CSS class that looks like `.btn-info` when you're not over the button, and looks like `.btn-danger` when hovering over it.

Comment: You can't. Maybe you can mimic it with CSS but solution is JS.

Comment: @cello, what is the easiest way to make it "look like" `.btn-danger`?

Comment: @Confiqure Alexis's answer bellow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the *:hover* selector. Have just tested the below method and seems to work okay

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Button</a>


.btn-info:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #d9534f;
 border-color: #d43f3a;
}
```

I have taken the hover style straight from the btn-danger class.

Comment: I guess there is no way to automatically inherit from `.btn-danger`?

Comment: @Confiqure There are tools like [LESS](http://www.lesscss.org/), which allow you to compose CSS at a higher level of abstraction, which would enable you to do this, but no straight forward way I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery code will do what you want, just give you button one more class `.my-btn`.

```
$('.my-btn').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-danger');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).addClass('btn-info').removeClass('btn-danger');
  }
});
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emrEvv)

Comment: I like this approach, but this doesn't seem to work for me? I put this in the `<head>` at the very end. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put it in `<script>` tag and add `my-btn` class on your button and it should work.

Comment: @Confiqure try it again, there was additional dot in class name, my bad, codepen works though.

Answer (score 0):

you cant change a node's clas with css but you can do something like this
default:

```
.btn-info{
 border:1px solid green;
}
```

hovering:

```
.btn-info:hover{
 border:2px solid red;
}
```